# How do you calculate the number of days in the current year?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know there are 365 days, but I wanted a formula that accounts for leap years.

There doesn't seem to be *anything* out there even remotely related to this question, which is extremely surprising to me, so I just thought I'd ask here.

Answer (score 2):

let's agree that the first day of the year is always 1 of January and the last day is 31 of December

[image]

therefore to calculate number of days in given (current) year would be:

```
=DAYS(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 12, 31), DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 1))+1
```

[image: 0]

or alternative:

```
=DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 1, 1), DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 12, 31), "D")+1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(EOMONTH(TODAY(),{0,12}-MONTH(TODAY()))*{-1,1}))
```